# How do I highlight Africa and other regions using the Google Visualization Geochart?

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I'm trying to find a map solution that is possible to highlight and click on various regions, one region would be Africa.  I'm also looking for a solution that will work well with Angularjs.

I thought the [Google Visualization Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) might be suitable.  This allows the selection of regions using the region codes listed on the site.

I've tried adding a few regions, the only one I could get working was Australia (AU), the following don't work for me:

```
      ['Europe', 150], 
      ['Western Asia', 145],  
      ['Asia', 142],
      ['Africa', 002]
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f781vrkt/6/) I'm using to test this.

Am I doing something wrong or is there an issue with the chart itself?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24213392/highlight-continent-with-mouseover-using-google-visualization-api-geocharts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037689/google-geochart-doesnt-show-continents http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797933/google-geochart-set-selectected-country

Comment: For a good directive to get you going with Google Charts API and AngularJS, I recommend http://github.com/bouil/angular-google-chart/

Answer (score 0):

```
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Region Code', 'Continent', 'Popularity'],
          ['142', 'Asia', 200],
          ['150', 'Europe', 300],
          ['019', 'Americas', 400],
          ['009', 'Oceania', 600],
          ['002', 'Africa', 700]
      ]);

      var options = {
          resolution: 'continents'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hrhj9qs/) shows how to do it:

Comment: This should also help in using with angular:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680865/use-geocharts-in-angularjs